# How does this ruby "method" work?

Tags: ruby, class, object, methods, sinatra

I am working with [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) but I am completely new to Ruby and confused about what the below code is actually doing.

```
class Something < Sinatra::Base

   get '/' do
      'hello world'
   end

end
```

We don't seem to be defining a method. Are we calling the `get` method? If so, at what time is it called? I've not seen anything like this in other languages.

If we had 2 classes that extended Sinatra::Base how would Sinatra understand that the `get` applies to `Something` rather than the other class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As opposed to the way, e.g., Java functions, when you define classes in Ruby, Ruby is actually executing code. Kind of like Java's static blocks. So when you do e.g.

```
class Foo
  puts(self)
end
```

you will open a class (i.e. change the current `self` to `Foo`), within its context do a `puts` (which will print out the `Foo` class object), and then close the class (returning `self` to what it was before).

`get` is a method defined on `Sinatra::Base`. Thus, your code is actually interpreted as if it were

```
class Something < Sinatra::Base
  self.get('/') do
    'hello world'
  end
end
```

Because `self` (i.e. `Foo`) inherits from `Sinatra::Base`, that's a method we're invoking - and we're doing it as the `Something` class definition is being read.

What that method does, roughly, is keep a table of "things to do when GET request comes in". It remembers that when it sees URL `/`, it should do the block `do "hello world" end`; more-or-less like this (example code; the original is a bit more complex):

```
class Sinatra::Base
  WHAT_TO_DO_ON_GET = {}

  def self.get(url, &thing_to_do)
    WHAT_TO_DO_ON_GET[url] = thing_to_do
  end
end
```

The Sinatra runtime is just a loop that, when a GET request comes in, looks up the URL against `THINGS_TO_DO_ON_GET` and executes what it finds there.